# DirectX 2d WinForm Setup for SharpDX 2D

Tags: c#, winforms, directx, sharpdx

Im pretty new to DirectX and I have been trying to follow this tutorial but it doesnt really explain what any of these objects are and I want to be able to use this with WinForms or WPF in the future but I have no idea how to setup the devices for 2d drawing. does anyone mind showing me exactly you do that ?  I attempted this but it I just get a sharpdx exception when the set the the varible d2dTarget.

````
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.ComponentModel;
using SharpDX;
using SharpDX.DXGI;
using SharpDX.Direct3D;
using SharpDX.Direct3D11;
using SharpDX.Direct2D1;

namespace SharpDX_Tester
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SharpDX.Direct3D11.Device device;
        SharpDX.Direct3D11.DeviceContext1 d3dContext;
        SharpDX.Direct2D1.DeviceContext d2dContext;
        RenderTargetView targetView;
        SwapChain swapChain;
        Texture2D target;

        Bitmap1 d2dTarget;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


            SharpDX.Direct3D11.Device defaultDevice = new SharpDX.Direct3D11.Device(DriverType.Hardware, DeviceCreationFlags.Debug | DeviceCreationFlags.BgraSupport);

            device = defaultDevice.QueryInterface<SharpDX.Direct3D11.Device1>();
            
            d3dContext = device.ImmediateContext.QueryInterface<SharpDX.Direct3D11.DeviceContext1>();

            SharpDX.DXGI.Device2 dxgiDevice2 = device.QueryInterface<SharpDX.DXGI.Device2>();
            SharpDX.DXGI.Adapter dxgiAdapter = dxgiDevice2.Adapter;
            SharpDX.DXGI.Factory2 dxgiFactory2 = dxgiAdapter.GetParent<SharpDX.DXGI.Factory2>();
            SharpDX.Direct2D1.Device d2dDevice = new SharpDX.Direct2D1.Device(dxgiDevice2);
            d2dContext = new SharpDX.Direct2D1.DeviceContext(d2dDevice, SharpDX.Direct2D1.DeviceContextOptions.None);

            var scd = new SwapChainDescription()
            {
                BufferCount = 1,
                Flags = SwapChainFlags.None,
                IsWindowed = true, //WINDOWS
                ModeDescription = new ModeDescription(panel1.ClientSize.Width, panel1.ClientSize.Height, new Rational(60, 1), Format.R8G8B8A8_UNorm),
                OutputHandle = panel1.Handle/*<-Impotant*/,
                SampleDescription = new SampleDescription(1, 0),
                SwapEffect = SwapEffect.Discard,
                Usage = Usage.RenderTargetOutput
            };
            SharpDX.Direct3D11.Device.CreateWithSwapChain(SharpDX.Direct3D.DriverType.Hardware, DeviceCreationFlags.Debug, scd, out device, out swapChain);

            BitmapProperties1 properties = new BitmapProperties1(new PixelFormat(SharpDX.DXGI.Format.B8G8R8A8_UNorm, SharpDX.Direct2D1.AlphaMode.Premultiplied));
            Surface backBuffer = swapChain.GetBackBuffer<Surface>(0);
            d2dTarget = new Bitmap1(d2dContext, backBuffer, properties);

            /* IGNORE THIS
            target = Texture2D.FromSwapChain<Texture2D>(sc, 0);
            targetView = new RenderTargetView(device, target);
            device.ImmediateContext.OutputMerger.SetRenderTargets(targetView);
            */
        }
    }
    ```
````

Comment: sorry I forgot to post this the tutorial Im trying to  follow is here https://english.r2d2rigo.es/2012/07/04/basic-direct2d-drawing-with-sharpdx/

Answer (score 0):

You can't really use SharpDX if you don't know / understand DirectX, DXGI, Direct2D. Also you talk about the "future", but SharpDX is no longer active since 2 years https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX.

Your code has two problems:

- you recreate a device (with a swap chain) and use the D2D device context from the first device
- you don't need to specify the properties when creating the bitmap, they are implicit from the underlying DXGI surface

This is a code that should work:

```
// create D3D device & (DXGI) swap chain
var scd = new SwapChainDescription()
{
    BufferCount = 1,
    Flags = SwapChainFlags.None,
    IsWindowed = true,
    ModeDescription = new ModeDescription(panel1.ClientSize.Width, panel1.ClientSize.Height, new Rational(60, 1), Format.R8G8B8A8_UNorm),
    OutputHandle = panel1.Handle, // make sure this is not IntPtr.Zero
    SampleDescription = new SampleDescription(1, 0),
    SwapEffect = SwapEffect.Discard,
    Usage = Usage.RenderTargetOutput
};

SharpDX.Direct3D11.Device.CreateWithSwapChain(
    DriverType.Hardware,
    DeviceCreationFlags.Debug | DeviceCreationFlags.BgraSupport,
    scd,
    out device,
    out swapChain);

// get swap chain backbuffer
var backBuffer = swapChain.GetBackBuffer<Surface>(0);

// create DXGI & D2D devices context
var dxgiDevice = device.QueryInterface<SharpDX.DXGI.Device2>();
var d2dDevice = new SharpDX.Direct2D1.Device(dxgiDevice);
d2dContext = new SharpDX.Direct2D1.DeviceContext(
    d2dDevice,
    DeviceContextOptions.None);

// create target
d2dTarget = new Bitmap1(d2dContext, backBuffer);
```

Comment: thx Ill try it out later today once I get chance , and yeah I've been trying to learn DirectX from C++ tutorails but idk why but I just can't understand any of the objects and stuff and I can't really find anything on direct2d . Im not really trying to get into game development but I want something faster than GDI+

Comment: SharpDX is somewhat difficult to grasp because you can't compare the thousands of standard and official C/C++ samples out there with the SharpDX code, even when you know the C/C++ objects. That's why I've created this "DirectN" package https://github.com/smourier/DirectN where .NET code is very similar to native one.

Comment: ohho interesting , but I think Im gonna stick with SharpDX . Im not really interesting in DirectX 11 and the hardest part of following most tutorials was just figuring out how to actually get things onto the Form since Im trying to use DirectX with WinForms.